# FlowProgram vs. Program

Tags: rascal

I'm trying to use the FlowGraphsAndClassDiagrams skeleton as provided to TU Eindhoven. For the function buildGraph a FlowProgram should be given. I tried to run the following:

```
m = createM3FromEclipseProject(|project://eLib|);
FlowProgram p = createOFG(|project://eLib|);
rel[loc from, loc to] relations = buildGraph(p);
```

This yields the error message: expected FlowProgram, but got Program.

So, the question is, what is a FlowProgram and where is it defined? What is the difference between it and the program as created by createOFG?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a version difference. `createOFG` returns something of type `Program` which used to be in a previous version `FlowProgram`. So if you change `FlowProgram` to `Program` in your code it will work. Or you could ignore the type completely and use `p = createOFG(|project://eLib|);` and the type should be inferred for you.

Additional information:

- `Program` is defined in `lang::ofg::ast::FlowLanguage` as `data Program = program(set[Decl] decls, set[Stm] statements);`